# How to reboot a jailbroken iPhone on PC

Tags: iphone, c, jailbreak, reboot

I found a open source library called libimobiledevice, it seems that a function called restored_reboot can do that, then I wrote code like this:

```
void reboot(){
    restored_client_t client = NULL;
    restored_error_t result =  restored_client_new(device, &client, "mylabel");

    if(result == 0){
        result = restored_reboot(client);
        if(result != 0)
             fprintf(stderr, "failed to reboot: %d\n", result);
    }else{
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to create client, %d\n", result);
    }

    restored_client_free(client);
}
```

But failed, the restored_reboot returned -3 which means plist error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know if it's that what you are looking for, but if you need to reboot iphone and you have root privileges, you can just kill crucial system process, like

```
void reboot(){
    system("kill 1");
}
```

It not seems like elegant way to reboot phone, but it will do what you need.

Comment: I have already know how to reboot on iPhone, just call system("reboot") on iPhone with root privilege. What I want to do is this: start a windows executable on a PC, connect an iPhone with a USB cable, click a button on the window of that windows executable, and my iPhone will be rebooted.